# Align parent bottom not working well on android device

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, android-listview

I have this list view row lyout:

[image]

Here it's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/members"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:background="#CCCCCC" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_title_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_update_date_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="last update"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_event_type_icon_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/calendar_icon"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_goin_icon_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="@string/users_icon"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_going_number_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_goin_icon_TextView"
                android:text="12"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_image_ImageView"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_image_loader_ProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But here is how I see it on devices:
[image]

On older devices it's working as seen in graphical layout.

What is wrong with it?

**option 1:** removing `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout3"` from `android:id="@+id/members"` returns this on the device:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Besides using the `android:layout_alignBottom` property try to use `android:layout_below=""`.

Comment: checkout my answer. @Vlad loffe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out below code. I have done some changes like text and images according to my need to make proper layout. You can change it according to your layout.

I have added the layout_below property and set the gravity of some views to set the layout at bottom as per your need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/members"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:background="#CCCCCC" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_title_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_update_date_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="last update"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                 android:layout_below="@id/UserEventListViewRow_event_type_icon_TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_event_type_icon_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/UserEventListViewRow_title_TextView"
                android:text="calen"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_goin_icon_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="users_icon"
                android:layout_below="@id/UserEventListViewRow_title_TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_going_number_TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_goin_icon_TextView"
                android:text="12"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_image_ImageView"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_my_calendar" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/UserEventListViewRow_image_loader_ProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there is an error at this line: `android:layout_below="@id/UserEventListViewRow_event_type_icon_TextView"` (42)

Comment: Try out like `@+id/UserEventListViewRow_event_type_icon_TextView`

Comment: there is no error now, but the text not aligned to the bottom of the  `@+id/members` relative layout. It is below the upper text views.

Comment: @VladIoffe Are you talking about the text `1` ?

Comment: @GrlsHu the text view on the top on of them `UserEventListViewRow_title_TextView`.

Comment: How exactly you want that text ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50671/discussion-between-vlad-ioffe-and-grishu)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
   <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/members"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    ....
```

android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout3" this will make the bottom edge of this layout match the bottom edge of the given anchor view ID which is relativeLayout3, and this layout is wrapping content and top aligned in his parent.

Just remove this line `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout3`

Comment: this pulls the hole `@+id/members` in the graphical view. In the device the grey (`@+id/members` colored as #CCCCCC) is not pulled to bottom of the left layout (which holds the image view)

Comment: see the updated question for details (under option 1)

Answer (score 0):

try to use android:layout_below and android:layout_above. this properties are very comfortable in RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Create a LinearLayout inside the RelativeLayout and put your view inside the LinearLayout, and declare android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" inside the  LinearLayout. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/palmview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
  <ImageView 
    android:id = "@+id/palm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/palm"/>
```

And that LinearLayout would be inside a RelativeLayout.